# asp.net core mvc SelectList for filter

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I am working on an asp.net MVC Core 2.0 application.

I have a page which contains a list of items.

I want to put several Dropdown list at the top of this page. This Dropdowns are filters.

Here is an example:

Here is my cshtml view:

```
@model List<Person>

Genre : <select asp-items="ViewBag.genres"></select>

<table border="1">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
     <tr>
            <td>@item.name</td>
            <td>@item.genre</td>
            ...
      </tr>
}
```

Here is the associated controller action method:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(String selected_genre)
        {
            ViewBag.genres = new SelectList(new [] 
                {
                    new { id = "", name = "All" },
                    new { id = "1", name = "Male" },
                    new { id = "2", name = "Female" },
                    new { id = "3", name = "Don't know" },
                }, 
                "id", "name", selected_genre);
            ...
```

What i want to do is to reload the page when the users select something in the genre dropdown.

If the user selects "Female", i want the page to be reloaded:

http://myapplication/MyController/Index?selected_genre=2&param2=3

Please note there might be other filters (this is why i put param2=3 in my example).

I have managed to make it work with javascript (onchange event). It works but it is very ugly.

I want to know if there is a way to do this with ASP.Net core 2 functionalities

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Simply add your filters and params into a form

```
<form method="get" action="~/">
    <select name="selected_genre" asp-items="ViewBag.genres"></select>
    ...
</form>
```

If you have no submit button, you can use submit the form with the select's `onchange`.